# React Native + Expo: __fbbatchedbridge is undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

There are a lot of threads on the error message `__fbbatchedbridge is undefined`, none of the solutions seem to work for a React Native setup with Expo though.

**I'm currently running:**

- React Native: 18.0.1
- Expo: 18.0.4

The Error Message only comes up if JS Debugging is enabled.

Does anyone have any pointers or suggestions for me?

Comment: The only way to avoid the error message for me is to use "localhost" as host instead of "LAN".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was fixed with the latest Expo release: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/321